# Change the name of anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

A function object has a non-standard property called name. Does anyone know a way to change it? Or any other way to change the name of an anonymous function? It would be good if JavaScript could create dynamically named variables, but it seems it can only create public object properties name.
What am I trying to do? 
I'm trying to achieve something like this.

```
// o - literal object, or json
// c - string
function givemeConstructor(o, c, a}){
    var a = a || 'Object';
    // check other variables
    var cons;

    if(a === 'Object'){
        cons = function(){};
        for(p in o) cons.prototype[p] = o[p];
        cons.name = c;
    }
    else{
        // a way to create a constructor that inherits from a
        // adds object as new prototype
    }

    return cons;            
}

var cons = givemeConstructor({x:1,y:1, toString:function(){return '['+ x + ','+ y+'']'}, 'Point'})
```

Getting in the end an introspectable object.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem your trying to solve? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @phant0m I don't know about OP, but a good use seems getting more readable tracebacks.

Comment: @delnan: Changing the function name makes it more readable?

Comment: @user1689607 Yeah, that's what the question is about (for *anonymous* functions, because otherwise it's obviously trivial).

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(function(){}, "name")` says you cannot.

Comment: @delnan: Oh, I see, so that one can still dynamically generate your functions dynamically, but give them names.

Comment: Yes, the name of a function used as a constructor is its class identity, affirmed by instanceof operator.

Comment: @Alfgaar Do you mind posting an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on the pattern you're playing with here, but the confusion seems to be that adding a `name` property to a constructor function does not allow you to refer to it my that name. Its 'name' is whatever variable[s] you assign it to.

Based on what you've done so far this would I think give you what you want -

```
function givemeConstructor ( proto ){
    var tmp = function(){};
    tmp.prototype = proto;
    return tmp;
}

var Point = givemeConstructor( {x:1 ,y:1, toString:function(){return '['+ this.x + ','+ this.y +']' } } );
var p = new Point;
```

Notes:

1. your function needs to use `this.x` and `this.y` to access the variables in the prototype
2. your constructor cannot take `x` and `y` arguments if you do this
3. you can inspect `Point.prototype` or instantiate and inspect `p`
4. setting `Function.name` to `Point` is pretty pointless and won't change how the constructor is referenced.